ReactJS: Public index.html and Content-Security-Policy
I have the following in my public index.html for my ReactJS app:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
'unsafe-eval' localhost blob base64 https://js.stripe.com https://apis.google.com https://www.googletagmanager.com" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'" />

In Safari, I am still getting the following console errors:
Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

Refused to load blob:https://m.stripe.network/XXX because it does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

Refused to load https://js.stripe.com/v3 because it appears in neither the script-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

Refused to load https://apis.google.com/js/api.js because it appears in neither the script-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

Is there any reason that these should violate the CSP?

You have split your CSP into 3 different policies, and all content needs to pass all policies. In your case the scripts that you load must then also pass default-src, which only allows 'self' and 'unsafe-inline'. Rewrite your CSP to "default-src   ...; script-src   ...; style-src    ...;" This should fix scripts loaded from other hosts.
Blob is a scheme and needs to be rewritten as blob: with the trailing colon. base64 can be removed.

 is still giving me Refused to load data:application/font-woff;base64 for example

For that you need to add data:, just like blob:
